# Make maze smaller with SCSS, Javascript, and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I want to develop a maze, but the maze is bigger than the screen and i can't scroll down to see it.

I tried to change the height of the body, but that didn't work.

Can anyone see what that makes the maze so big?

[here](https://github.com/egb-dev/maze/) is all of my code on github.

[here](https://angry-bell-e68ecd.netlify.com/) is how it looks.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please attache a screenshot how it looks, so that everyone here looking at the question understands it better, or just put it in https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Sure! Just deleted all the code and put in a link to all the code!

Comment: I don't have the time to clone and run your project, but here is a wild guess: `body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; } .maze { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help, but thanks that you took some time to try to answer my question!

Comment: @DarpanRangari Maybe it's a mistake with linking the files together because . in codesandbox.io it looks totally fine! And I guess you don't have to link the files in codesandbox.io, right?

Comment: @egb-dev no linking file is not required.

Comment: include the code here in SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your layout posting on your **HTML** body elements. You're using the "fixed" position, and you should be using the "relative" position.

This should explain the difference and get you back on the right path.

Additionally, you can check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for posting.